# Sync Outlook on PC with Android Phone (Calendar, Contacts, Tasks and Notes)

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, android, sync

I have researched this extensively online and in SE, but I'm finding it hard to believe that in 2020 there is no native solution for synchronizing Outlook on a PC (calendar, contacts, tasks and notes) with an Android phone. Is there no way to do this without a third party app?

In case it matters, I'm using Windows 10 and have an Android Galaxy S20.

Comment: What is Outlook on PC connecting to? [Android's Outlook app allows you to sync](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/how-to-sync-outlook-contacts-with-android-iphone-gmail-more/). If you're using a Microsoft provider (e.g., Microsoft 365, Outlook, etc.), I'd imagine your best bet is using the Outlook app. [There are also sync instructions for the Gmail app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/can-t-sync-calendar-and-contacts-with-my-phone-or-tablet-8479d764-b9f5-4fff-ba88-edd7c265df9f#ID0EAACAAA=Gmail_app).

Comment: @singalongconflict That link only shows you how to sync Outlook contacts. As per my question, I'm interested in syncing all Outlook data (calendar, contacts, tasks and notes) with my phone. Ideally it would be great if there was one unified app on Android that stored all the data (e.g. Outlook on Android), but more than one app would be OK as long as there isn't third party middleware involved (which as stated in my question is my core issue).

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of your email account? POP, IMAP or Exchange? As I know, if you are using Exchange account, the emails, calendar, contacts and tasks are all synced with the mail server and you could achieve them when adding your email account to your Outlook.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. It's an IMAP account (it's a personal device, not a work device so I don't have an Exchange account). I didn't know Exchange also synced other data - does it also sync Outlook notes?

Comment: As I tested, Exchange account syncs Outlook notes as well. However, it seems that  Outlook for mobile has not supported the note feature so far.